# Hadith on half of man’s religion fulfilled through marriage

Tags: hadith-interpretation, men-women

*If half a man’s religion is fulfilled through marriage, what about for the wife? Is it the same for the wives in this case?*

https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2013/04/16/nikah-half-deen/

Comment: A variation of the hadith appears in [Mishkat al Masabih](https://sunnah.com/mishkat:3096)"Anas reported God’s Messenger as saying, “When a man marries he has fulfilled half of the religion; so let him fear God regarding the remaining half.”

Answer (score 1):

Islam treats women and men equally. Allah would not grant such an opportunity to a man, that he would prevent from a woman based on gender alone. Faith is another story. There are versions of this hadith that do does not say the word 'man' in it, but I cannot find the authenticity for them. Allah is not racist in any way, that is a sin to believe in. He is the most just being to ever exist. Here is another version of the hadith:

> Prophet Muhammad, peace and blessings upon him, said “Whoever marries has achieved one half of one’s religion.”

Comment: Contrary to what the other person said there are things in Islam which is different between men and women. Without any proof you cannot claim that same goes for women. Adding something new to the deen is innovation. There are lots of instances in the deen where men and women have different responsibilities and get rewarded for doing different things. For example women get more reward for praying at home while men get more reward for praying in jammaa.